# How to re-render a component after executing a function in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a `Counter` component that needs to be re-rendered after the `buy` function is executed.

I created a variable `let reFreshCounter = ref(1)` After executing the function, I add **1** to `reFreshCounter`.
In the template my component looks like this: `<Counter :key="reFreshCounter"/>`

**Is it good practice to do this or is there a better way?**

Comment: If there's something that `buy()` changes that the Counter component somehow reflects, you could relate the two with props/events, or maybe a watcher.  Without knowing what either does, it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Either you are passing the actual count, or whether it goes up or down. In any way, if you want to keep the value in counter and/or update it, the component should update automatically. I also don't know why you are using ref here.

Comment: If you want to rerender a given component - add `:key="refresh"` in your template and then either increment `refresh` (if it is integer) or toggle it (if it is a boolean)